# Exporting issues when ssrs report is connected to different data sources

Tags: reporting-services, header, export, datasource, missing-data

I have a ssrs report that when connected to one datasource (dev server), it runs correctly and exports to PDF correctly. When I take that same report and connect it to another datasource (test server) and run it, it runs correctly, but when I export to PDF (and this is the same with tiff, word) I am missing some of the header text boxes? But when I export to Excel, I can see the header text boxes.

Any thoughts? Does the report inherit some attributes from the data source it is connected to?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: SOLVED: One of the text boxes in the report header was getting the report title from the database. On the dev server the length was 10 characters, but on the test server the value had the 10 characters plus another 200 spaces added to the end. All I had to do was trim the value when I was using it in the report. Report Server was able to render the report with the extra spaces but when I exported it to PDF it kept the extra spaces and pushed all the rest of the text boxes out of sight.